# Android Calendar Intent Code Explanation

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-intent, calendar

I wanted to open up the android native calendar application on a button click in my application. I have searched online and I have found the code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", eventStartInMillis);
intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);

startActivity(intent);
```

Could someone please explain this code to me?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Read the documentation, it helps.

Comment: I did read the documentation, but I don't understand it, that's why I came here. I basically understand the first and the last line. I want to know what the rest of the lines do and what their significance is to opening the calendar app.

Comment: For example, why do I need intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
? its not like I am trying to add a title or anything. All I want is to open the app.

Comment: You do understand *what the code does* just not why it's needed :-) Based on a quick glance at other SO questions, you need this since it's hard to open the calendar app, you're not really meant to do so. This is a workaround by creating an event. The calendar app has to respond, and voila - calendar "open".

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. Will this create a listing in the calendar (I don't want it to make a listing)? If so, is there a way to delete the listing so that the calendar is unchanged?

Comment: Haven't messed with this, but it should just open up the "edit" portion (as in just *before* you make an event). How this is handled may vary based on API version.

Comment: I think this is correct, how do I set your answer as correct?

Comment: Also I found a better way to integrate the google calendar into an Android application. You can create application through PhoneGap and link the app to https://www.google.com/calendar. There you can open the mobile or calendar gmail calendar. The only downside is you are not using a native system.

Comment: I wouldn't know anything about phonegap, I just deal with native code such as the one in your question. Also, only answers can be accepted, not comments. I'll see if I can make my comments answer-worthy.

Comment: It is now an answer. See if my last code snippet works.

Comment: If my answer answered your question, you should accept it by clicking the hollowed out checkmark so it turns green. If you have any comments, leave them down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question about what the code does

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
```

Creates a new `Intent` corresponding with the `Intent` Action [`ACTION_EDIT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EDIT). This is a generic Intent Action, meaning that just this isn't enough to launch the right `Activity` automatically. This is why the next thing we do is set the MIME type of the `Intent`. Since we want to launch the Calendar editor, we set the type to `vnd.android.cursor.item/event`:

```
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
```

This corresponds with the manifest entry. Notice the `data` node (Jellybean version manifest shown).

```html
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <!-- mime type -->
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

The `putExtra()` calls allow you to specify event characteristics such as title of the event, start and end time, etc.

Then we start the Activity. The result is something like this:

[image]

And there you go, you have opened the Android calendar app to add an event!

*Warning: Mileage may vary*

But what if you don't want to call on the event editor? If all you want is to open up the Android calendar app, you can use `PackageManager#getLaunchIntentForPackage()` (provided that: the package name doesn't change, the Android calendar is installed, and that you can get a reference to the `PackageManager`).

Example from an Activity (using MainActivity.this to highlight the fact that I'm launching from an Activity):

```
Intent i = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.calendar");
if (i != null)
  startActivity(i);
```